# How do I diagnose a Kubernetes cluster that never becomes ready?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I deployed an image to  Kubernetes, but it never becomes ready, even after hours.

```
$ kubectl get pods

NAME                            READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
myapp-b8dd974db-9jbsl    0/1       ImagePullBackOff   0          21m
```

All this happens with the Quickstart [Hello app](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/quickstart), as well as my own Docker image.

Attempts to attach fail.

```
$ kubectl attach -it  myapp-b8dd974db-9jbs

Unable to use a TTY - container myapp did not allocate one
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
error: unable to upgrade connection: container 
   myapp not found in pod myapp-b8dd974db-9jbsl_default
```

Attempts to access it over HTTP fail.

In Stackdriver Logging I see messages like

```
skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "myapp"
with ImagePullBackOff: "Back-off pulling image 
\"gcr.io/myproject/myapp-image:1.0\""
```

and `No such image`

Yet I did deploy these images and the Cloud Console shows that the pods are "green."

And `kubectl` seems to tell me that the cluster is OK.

```
$ kubectl get service myapp
NAME           TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)          AGE
myapp   LoadBalancer   10.43.248.78   35.193.107.141   8222:31840/TCP   29m
```

How can I diagnose this?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `kubectl describe myapp-b8dd974db-9jbsl` to get more information on your pod.

But from the status message 'ImagePullBackOff' it is probably trying to download the docker image and failing.

This might because of several reasons, you will obtain more information with the `kubectl describe` but it's probably that you don't have permissions to that docker repository or the image/image:tag does not exist.

Comment: Interesting -- I just redeployed the Hello example and now  that one has Running where the older one has ImagePullBackOff.

Comment: So is it working now? Have you used the describe command? After it's running you can also use `kubectl logs myapp-b8dd974db-9jbsl` to get the output of the container

Comment: I redid the build sequence and succeeded. Possible I omitted docker push in some cases, yet  did it correctly in others.  Thank you.